# ¿Como puedo mover los caballos en la posion L en un cuadro de 3x3?

Tags: python, bucle-for, matrices

Hola buenas tengo un problema de caballos blancos y negros en como moverlos en posición L, en este código en cada función da una vuelta de como de 45° hasta hacer que las piezas blancas y negras den una vuelta completa hasta la posición en la que iniciaron, pero que se usando la forma en que se mueven los caballos en el ajedrez. Este es el código que estoy usando:

```py
chessBoard = [["N", "▢", "N"], ["▢", "▢", "▢"], ["B", "▢", "B"]]

# def printBoard(columnList):
#    fila = len(columnList)
#    columna = len(columnList[0])
#    for i in range(fila):
#            for j in range(columna):
#                print(" {0} ".format(columnList[i][j]), sep=',', end='')
#            print('')


def rotar_matriz(matriz):
    rotada = []
    for i in range(len(matriz[0])):
        rotada.append([])
        for j in range(len(matriz)):
            rotada[i].append(matriz[len(matriz) - 1 - j][i])
    return rotada


print("\n-----------------------\n")
for fila in chessBoard:
    for e in fila:
        print(e, sep=",", end=" ")
print()
print("\n-----------------------\n")

rotada_1 = rotar_matriz(chessBoard)
for fila in rotada_1:
    for e in fila:
        print(e, sep=",", end=" ")
print()
print("\n-----------------------\n")

rotada_2 = rotar_matriz(rotada_1)
for fila in rotada_2:
    for e in fila:
        print(e, sep=",", end=" ")
print()
print("\n-----------------------\n")

rotada_3 = rotar_matriz(rotada_2)
for fila in rotada_3:
    for e in fila:
        print(e, sep=",", end=" ")
print()
print("\n-----------------------\n")

rotada_4 = rotar_matriz(rotada_3)
for fila in rotada_4:
    for e in fila:
        print(e, sep=",", end=" ")
print()
print("\n-----------------------\n")
print("\n***********************\n")
# printBoard(chessBoard)
print("\n***********************\n")
```

De este codigo tiene el primer N se mueva a la derecha 2 veces luego baje un 1 que daria en la posicion L, asi como el blanco abajo de la primer negra tiene que subir 2 veces luego ir a la derecha en 1 que cada pieza se mueva en L en sentido de la derecha pero que no se este muy cerca del otro pegados, como un cuadrado lo giran aparece rombo cuadrado luego lo giras otra vez es cuadrado de nuevo lo giras de nuevo sale rombo lo giras como de 4 a 6 veces en L cada uno sin que se toquen hasta que den una vuelta

Comment: No entiendo tu problema. Tienes un tablero de 3x3, tienes 2 caballos (Negro y Blanco) y luego que hay que hacer?

Comment: ya modifique un poco en la seccion de abajo de la pregunta tiene que moverse todas las peizas en posicion L a la derecha hasta que las peizas negras queden en el lugar de las blancas y las blancas en la posicion de las negras

Comment: En un movimiento se mueven las 4 al mismo tiempo, o se mueven como el ajedrez una en una, si es así cual mueve primero?

Comment: Este es el problema ??? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdNpwVaPa-E

Comment: Si es como el video en un cuadro los 4 caballos se movieron a la derecha en L una tras otra, luego que pase lo mismo en otro cuadro una y otra vez mas hasta que los negros pasen abajo y los blancos arriba

Comment: Tal vez las Torres de Hanoi te puedan servir de inspiración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nota: Esta respuesta ha sido editada para incluir la rotación final.

El tablero está representado como una lista de listas, donde cada casilla es un caracter

```
tablero = [
    ['W', ' ', 'W'],
    [' ', ' ', ' '],
    ['B', ' ', 'B']
]
```

Una función para imprimir el tablero. Nada complicado

```
def imprimir(board):
    print()
    row = board[0]
    print(f"{row[0]} | {row[1]} | {row[2]}")
    print("--+---+---")
    row = board[1]
    print(f"{row[0]} | {row[1]} | {row[2]}")
    print("--+---+---")
    row = board[2]
    print(f"{row[0]} | {row[1]} | {row[2]}")
```

La función de rotación, que recibe una matriz y la rota 90° contra el reloj:

```
def rotar(board):
    nuevo = []
    for col in reversed(range(3)):
        nuevo.append([board[i][col] for i in range(3)])
    return nuevo
```

La función `mover` mueve una pieza de la `pos1` a la `pos2`. La movida tiene que ser legal. No es realmente necesario revisar que la casilla `pos2` esté desocupada; el método asegura que lo esté.

```
def mover(board, pos1, pos2):
    # pos1 y pos2 son dos tuplas (fila, columna)
    row, col = pos1
    row2, col2 = pos2
    piece = board[row2][col2]
    if piece == ' ':
        board[row2][col2] = board[row][col]
        board[row][col] = ' '
    imprimir(board)
```

La función `intercambia` realiza las movidas elementales para intercambiar dos piezas

```
def intercambia(board):
    #
    #   Intercambia esq. sup. izq. con esq. inf. izq.
    #
    mover(board, (0,0), (1,2))
    mover(board, (2,0), (0,1))
    mover(board, (1,2), (2,0))
    mover(board, (2,2), (1,0))
    mover(board, (0,2), (2,1))
    mover(board, (2,1), (0,0))
    mover(board, (1,0), (0,2))
    mover(board, (0,1), (2,2))
```

#### Demo

```
imprimir(tablero)
intercambia(tablero)
print("rotación")
imprimir(rotar(tablero))
```

produce

```
W |   | W
--+---+---
  |   |  
--+---+---
B |   | B

  |   | W
--+---+---
  |   | W
--+---+---
B |   | B

  | B | W
--+---+---
  |   | W
--+---+---
  |   | B

  | B | W
--+---+---
  |   |  
--+---+---
W |   | B

  | B | W
--+---+---
B |   |  
--+---+---
W |   |  

  | B |  
--+---+---
B |   |  
--+---+---
W | W |  

W | B |  
--+---+---
B |   |  
--+---+---
W |   |  

W | B | B
--+---+---
  |   |  
--+---+---
W |   |  

W |   | B
--+---+---
  |   |  
--+---+---
W |   | B


rotación

B |   | B
--+---+---
  |   |  
--+---+---
W |   | W

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Si este codigo es lo que necesitaba nadamas faltaba un poco de que las 4 piezas se muevan todas a la derecha del otro en L en una luego en otra hasta dar como 6 vueltas para que las blancos y negros esten en el lugar del otro